# Two Laurent polynomials actually being equal

Tags: co.combinatorics

I encountered two Laurent polynomials
$$\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{
\mbox{$\begin{array}{c}
i_1,\dots,i_k\geq 0\\
i_0=-N-i_1-\dots-i_k\end{array}$}}
\sum_{m=0}^{i_j}
  \begin{pmatrix}
        -N\\
        i_1,\dots,i_k
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
        i_j\\
        m
  \end{pmatrix}
x_0^{i_0}\cdots x^{i_j-m}\cdots x_k^{i_k}
$$ and
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{N\geq p_1\geq\cdots\geq p_{n}\geq 0}
\sum_{
\mbox{$\begin{array}{c}
i_1,\dots,i_k\geq 0\\
i_0=-N-i_1-\dots-i_k-p_1-\cdots- p_{n}\end{array}$}}
\begin{pmatrix}
        N\\
        p_1
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        p_1\\
        p_2
  \end{pmatrix}\cdots
\begin{pmatrix}
        p_{n-1}\\
        p_{n}
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        -(N+p_1+\cdots+p_n)\\
        i_1,\dots,i_k
  \end{pmatrix}
x_0^{i_0}\cdots x^{i_j+p_1+\cdots+p_n}\cdots x_k^{i_k},
$$
where $N,n,k$ are given positive integers and
$$  
\begin{pmatrix}
        l\\
        i_1,\dots,i_k
  \end{pmatrix}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
        l\\
        i_1
  \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
        l-i_1\\
        i_2
  \end{pmatrix}\cdots
 \begin{pmatrix}
        l-i_1-\cdots-i_{k-1}\\
        i_k
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
for any integer $l$, positive integers $i_1,\dots,i_k$.
I need to prove that they are actually the same.
Can anyone help me? or just give me some hint.
I'll be grateful.

Comment: Did you check that they are the same? (Say, by a computer experiment.) Accidentally, what are the parameters? $N$ and $k$? At first sight, your "polynomials" look more like power series.

Comment: There is no $i_0$, so $j$ should run in both sums from 1 to k. Using $\sum_{m=0}^{i}  \binom imx^{i-m}=\sum_{m=0}^{i}  \binom imx^{m}=(1+x)^i$ with $i=i_j$ repeatedly for each $j$, you should come up with some power of $(k+x)$ for both expressions. I wonder though if your summations are well-defined.